# How can I decrease loading time of scripts in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Issues

I am building a card builder app and the builder is split into three sections; the create (user enters details), the builder (using vue.draggable user can drag stamps on to card) and the preview (card is displayed to user).

I use jQuery to fade each section in and out and I want to increase the speed of the loading time - my issues is that when the build section is first loaded in, it takes a long time, but then it works as expected.

### Failed Solutions

I first thought that is was the `png` stamp images that were increasing the loading time and so I uploaded them to [compress.io](https://compressor.io/) and this decreased the image sizes from 406KB to 82KB

I then research some solutions and tried compressing the jQuery the original file looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    let btn1 = $('#btn-1')
    let btn2 = $('#btn-2')
    let btn3 = $('#btn-3')
    let btn1Txt = $('#btn-1-txt')
    let btn2Txt = $('#btn-2-txt')
    let btn3Txt = $('#btn-3-txt')
    let create = $('.create-container')
    let build = $('.build-container')
    let preview = $('.preview-container')

    let cardTitle
    let cardDescription
    let logoAlign
    let logoShape
    let cardSlots
    let cardColour


    btn1.addClass('active-btn')
    btn1Txt.addClass('active-txt')

    create.fadeIn(250)

    btn1.click(function () {
        btn1.addClass('active-btn')
        btn1Txt.addClass('active-txt')
        btn2.removeClass('active-btn')
        btn2Txt.removeClass('active-txt')
        btn3.removeClass('active-btn')
        btn3Txt.removeClass('active-txt')

        build.fadeOut(100)
        preview.fadeOut(100)
        create.delay(250).fadeIn(100)
    });

    btn2.click(function () {
        btn2.addClass('active-btn')
        btn2Txt.addClass('active-txt')
        btn1.removeClass('active-btn')
        btn1Txt.removeClass('active-txt')
        btn3.removeClass('active-btn')
        btn3Txt.removeClass('active-txt')

        create.fadeOut(100)
        preview.fadeOut(100)
        build.delay(250).fadeIn(100)
    });

    btn3.click(function () {
        btn3.addClass('active-btn')
        btn3Txt.addClass('active-txt')
        btn1.removeClass('active-btn')
        btn1Txt.removeClass('active-txt')
        btn2.removeClass('active-btn')
        btn2Txt.removeClass('active-txt')

        create.fadeOut(100)
        build.fadeOut(100)
        preview.delay(250).fadeIn(100)
    });


    let titleHelper = $('#title-helper')
    let titleHelpShow = $('#title-helper-show')
    let titleHelpHide = $('#title-helper-close')
    let titleInput = $('#title-input')

    let descHelper = $('#desc-helper')
    let descHelpShow = $('#desc-helper-show')
    let descHelpHide = $('#desc-helper-close')
    let descInput = $('#desc-input')

    let logoHelper = $('#logo-helper')
    let logoHelpShow = $('#logo-helper-show')
    let logoHelpHide = $('#logo-helper-close')

    let logoShapeHelper = $('#logo-shape-helper')
    let logoShapeHelpShow = $('#logo-shape-helper-show')
    let logoShapeHelpHide = $('#logo-shape-helper-close')

    let colourHelper = $('#colour-helper')
    let colourHelpShow = $('#colour-helper-show')
    let colourHelpHide = $('#colour-helper-close')
    let colourInput = $('#colour-input')

    let numHelper = $('#num-helper')
    let numHelpShow = $('#num-helper-show')
    let numHelpHide = $('#num-helper-close')
    let numInput = $('#num-input')

    let alignLeft = $('#align-left-opt')
    let alignCenter = $('#align-center-opt')
    let alignRight = $('#align-right-opt')

    let circleLogo = $('#circle-logo')
    let squareLogo = $('#square-logo')

    let stamp5 = $('#stamps-5')
    let stamp10 = $('#stamps-10')
    let stamp15 = $('#stamps-15')
    let colourPicker = $('#colour-input')


    titleHelpShow.click(function() {titleHelper.fadeIn(200)});
    titleHelpHide.click(function() {titleHelper.fadeOut(200)});
    titleInput.click(function() {titleHelper.fadeOut(200)});

    descHelpShow.click(function() {descHelper.fadeIn(200)});
    descHelpHide.click(function() {descHelper.fadeOut(200)});
    descInput.click(function() {descHelper.fadeOut(200)});

    logoHelpShow.click(function() {logoHelper.fadeIn(200)});
    logoHelpHide.click(function() {logoHelper.fadeOut(200)});

    alignLeft.click(function() {logoHelper.fadeOut(200)});
    alignCenter.click(function() {logoHelper.fadeOut(200)});
    alignRight.click(function() {logoHelper.fadeOut(200)});

    logoShapeHelpShow.click(function() {logoShapeHelper.fadeIn(200)});
    logoShapeHelpHide.click(function() {logoShapeHelper.fadeOut(200)});
    circleLogo.click(function() {logoShapeHelper.fadeOut(200)});
    squareLogo.click(function() {logoShapeHelper.fadeOut(200)});

    numHelpShow.click(function() {numHelper.fadeIn(200)});
    numHelpHide.click(function() {numHelper.fadeOut(200)});
    numInput.click(function() {numHelper.fadeOut(200)});
    stamp5.click(function() {numHelper.fadeOut(200)});
    stamp10.click(function() {numHelper.fadeOut(200)});
    stamp15.click(function() {numHelper.fadeOut(200)});

    colourHelpShow.click(function() {colourHelper.fadeIn(200)});
    colourHelpHide.click(function() {colourHelper.fadeOut(200)});
    colourInput.click(function() {colourHelper.fadeOut(200)});

    alignLeft.click(function() {
        alignRight.removeClass('active-btn')
        alignCenter.removeClass('active-btn')
        alignLeft.addClass('active-btn')
    });

    alignCenter.click(function () {
        alignRight.removeClass('active-btn')
        alignLeft.removeClass('active-btn')
        alignCenter.addClass('active-btn')
    });

    alignRight.click(function () {
        alignLeft.removeClass('active-btn')
        alignCenter.removeClass('active-btn')
        alignRight.addClass('active-btn')
    });

    circleLogo.click(function () {
        squareLogo.removeClass('active-btn')
        circleLogo.addClass('active-btn')
    });
    
    squareLogo.click(function () {
        circleLogo.removeClass('active-btn')
        squareLogo.addClass('active-btn')
    });

    stamp5.click(function () {
        stamp10.removeClass('active-btn')
        stamp15.removeClass('active-btn')
        stamp5.addClass('active-btn')
    });

    stamp10.click(function () {    
        stamp5.removeClass('active-btn')
        stamp15.removeClass('active-btn')
        stamp10.addClass('active-btn')
    });

    stamp15.click(function () {
        stamp10.removeClass('active-btn')
        stamp5.removeClass('active-btn')
        stamp15.addClass('active-btn')
    });

    cardTitle = "Untitled Card"
    cardDescription = "This is the card Description"
    logoAlign = "Left"
    logoShape = "Square"
    cardSlots = 5
    cardColour = colourPicker.val()

    titleInput.change(function() {cardTitle = titleInput.val()});
    
    descInput.change(function() {cardDescription = descInput.val()});
    
    alignLeft.click(function() {logoAlign = "Left"});
    alignCenter.click(function() {logoAlign = "Center"});
    alignRight.click(function() {logoAlign = "Right"});

    circleLogo.click(function() {logoShape = "Circle"});
    squareLogo.click(function() {logoShape = "Square"});

    stamp5.click(function () {cardSlots = 5});
    stamp10.click(function () {cardSlots = 10});
    stamp15.click(function () {cardSlots = 15});

    colourPicker.change(function() {cardColour = colourPicker.val()});

    let logo = $('.sample-logo-container')
    let logoPosition = $('.logo-align-container')
    let cardHolder = $('.builder-card')
    let stampRow1 = $('#stamp-row-1')
    let stampRow2 = $('#stamp-row-2')
    let stampRow3 = $('#stamp-row-3')


    btn2.click(function () {
        console.log("Title: " + cardTitle)
        console.log("Description: " + cardDescription)
        console.log("Logo Alignment: " + logoAlign)
        console.log("Logo Shape: " + logoShape)
        console.log("Num of stamps: " + cardSlots)
        console.log("Background Colour: " + cardColour)

        if (logoShape === "Square") {
            logo.removeClass('circle-logo')
            logo.addClass('square-logo')
        }

        if (logoShape === "Circle") {
            logo.removeClass('square-logo')
            logo.addClass('circle-logo')
        }

        if (logoAlign === "Left") {
            logoPosition.removeClass('logo-align-middle')
            logoPosition.removeClass('logo-align-right')
            logo.removeClass('logo-align-middle')
            logo.removeClass('m-inline-e')
            logoPosition.addClass('logo-align-left')
            logo.addClass('m-inline-s')
        }

        if (logoAlign === "Center") {
            logoPosition.removeClass('logo-align-left')
            logoPosition.removeClass('logo-align-right')
            logo.removeClass('m-inline-s')
            logo.removeClass('m-inline-e')
            logoPosition.addClass('logo-align-middle')
            logo.addClass('logo-align-middle')
        }

        if (logoAlign === "Right") {
            logoPosition.removeClass('logo-align-left')
            logoPosition.removeClass('logo-align-middle')
            logo.removeClass('m-inline-s')
            logo.removeClass('logo-align-middle')
            logoPosition.addClass('logo-align-right')
            logo.addClass('m-inline-e')
        }

        if (cardSlots === 5) {
            stampRow1.show()
            stampRow2.hide()
            stampRow3.hide()
            cardHolder.removeClass('two-stamp-row-height')
            cardHolder.removeClass('three-stamp-row-height')
            cardHolder.addClass('one-stamp-row-height')
        }

        if (cardSlots === 10) {
            stampRow1.show()
            stampRow2.show()
            stampRow3.hide()
            cardHolder.removeClass('one-stamp-row-height')
            cardHolder.removeClass('three-stamp-row-height')
            cardHolder.addClass('two-stamp-row-height')
        }

        if (cardSlots === 15) {
            stampRow1.show()
            stampRow2.show()
            stampRow3.show()
            cardHolder.removeClass('one-stamp-row-height')
            cardHolder.removeClass('two-stamp-row-height')
            cardHolder.addClass('three-stamp-row-height')
        }

        cardHolder.css("background-color", cardColour)
    });
});
```

And the compressed file looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){let e=$("#btn-1"),t=$("#btn-2"),l=$("#btn-3"),a=$("#btn-1-txt"),o=$("#btn-2-txt"),c=$("#btn-3-txt"),i=$(".create-container"),n=$(".build-container"),s=$(".preview-container"),d,r,u,v,f,m;e.addClass("active-btn"),a.addClass("active-txt"),i.fadeIn(250),e.click(function(){e.addClass("active-btn"),a.addClass("active-txt"),t.removeClass("active-btn"),o.removeClass("active-txt"),l.removeClass("active-btn"),c.removeClass("active-txt"),n.fadeOut(100),s.fadeOut(100),i.delay(250).fadeIn(100)}),t.click(function(){t.addClass("active-btn"),o.addClass("active-txt"),e.removeClass("active-btn"),a.removeClass("active-txt"),l.removeClass("active-btn"),c.removeClass("active-txt"),i.fadeOut(100),s.fadeOut(100),n.delay(250).fadeIn(100)}),l.click(function(){l.addClass("active-btn"),c.addClass("active-txt"),e.removeClass("active-btn"),a.removeClass("active-txt"),t.removeClass("active-btn"),o.removeClass("active-txt"),i.fadeOut(100),n.fadeOut(100),s.delay(250).fadeIn(100)});let C=$("#title-helper"),g=$("#title-helper-show"),h=$("#title-helper-close"),p=$("#title-input"),k=$("#desc-helper"),b=$("#desc-helper-show"),w=$("#desc-helper-close"),O=$("#desc-input"),x=$("#logo-helper"),I=$("#logo-helper-show"),q=$("#logo-helper-close"),L=$("#logo-shape-helper"),y=$("#logo-shape-helper-show"),S=$("#logo-shape-helper-close"),D=$("#colour-helper"),R=$("#colour-helper-show"),T=$("#colour-helper-close"),A=$("#colour-input"),B=$("#num-helper"),N=$("#num-helper-show"),U=$("#num-helper-close"),j=$("#num-input"),z=$("#align-left-opt"),E=$("#align-center-opt"),F=$("#align-right-opt"),G=$("#circle-logo"),H=$("#square-logo"),J=$("#stamps-5"),K=$("#stamps-10"),M=$("#stamps-15"),P=$("#colour-input");g.click(function(){C.fadeIn(200)}),h.click(function(){C.fadeOut(200)}),p.click(function(){C.fadeOut(200)}),b.click(function(){k.fadeIn(200)}),w.click(function(){k.fadeOut(200)}),O.click(function(){k.fadeOut(200)}),I.click(function(){x.fadeIn(200)}),q.click(function(){x.fadeOut(200)}),z.click(function(){x.fadeOut(200)}),E.click(function(){x.fadeOut(200)}),F.click(function(){x.fadeOut(200)}),y.click(function(){L.fadeIn(200)}),S.click(function(){L.fadeOut(200)}),G.click(function(){L.fadeOut(200)}),H.click(function(){L.fadeOut(200)}),N.click(function(){B.fadeIn(200)}),U.click(function(){B.fadeOut(200)}),j.click(function(){B.fadeOut(200)}),J.click(function(){B.fadeOut(200)}),K.click(function(){B.fadeOut(200)}),M.click(function(){B.fadeOut(200)}),R.click(function(){D.fadeIn(200)}),T.click(function(){D.fadeOut(200)}),A.click(function(){D.fadeOut(200)}),z.click(function(){F.removeClass("active-btn"),E.removeClass("active-btn"),z.addClass("active-btn")}),E.click(function(){F.removeClass("active-btn"),z.removeClass("active-btn"),E.addClass("active-btn")}),F.click(function(){z.removeClass("active-btn"),E.removeClass("active-btn"),F.addClass("active-btn")}),G.click(function(){H.removeClass("active-btn"),G.addClass("active-btn")}),H.click(function(){G.removeClass("active-btn"),H.addClass("active-btn")}),J.click(function(){K.removeClass("active-btn"),M.removeClass("active-btn"),J.addClass("active-btn")}),K.click(function(){J.removeClass("active-btn"),M.removeClass("active-btn"),K.addClass("active-btn")}),M.click(function(){K.removeClass("active-btn"),J.removeClass("active-btn"),M.addClass("active-btn")}),d="Untitled Card",r="This is the card Description",u="Left",v="Square",f=5,m=P.val(),p.change(function(){d=p.val()}),O.change(function(){r=O.val()}),z.click(function(){u="Left"}),E.click(function(){u="Center"}),F.click(function(){u="Right"}),G.click(function(){v="Circle"}),H.click(function(){v="Square"}),J.click(function(){f=5}),K.click(function(){f=10}),M.click(function(){f=15}),P.change(function(){m=P.val()});let Q=$(".sample-logo-container"),V=$(".logo-align-container"),W=$(".builder-card"),X=$("#stamp-row-1"),Y=$("#stamp-row-2"),Z=$("#stamp-row-3");t.click(function(){console.log("Title: "+d),console.log("Description: "+r),console.log("Logo Alignment: "+u),console.log("Logo Shape: "+v),console.log("Num of stamps: "+f),console.log("Background Colour: "+m),"Square"===v&&(Q.removeClass("circle-logo"),Q.addClass("square-logo")),"Circle"===v&&(Q.removeClass("square-logo"),Q.addClass("circle-logo")),"Left"===u&&(V.removeClass("logo-align-middle"),V.removeClass("logo-align-right"),Q.removeClass("logo-align-middle"),Q.removeClass("m-inline-e"),V.addClass("logo-align-left"),Q.addClass("m-inline-s")),"Center"===u&&(V.removeClass("logo-align-left"),V.removeClass("logo-align-right"),Q.removeClass("m-inline-s"),Q.removeClass("m-inline-e"),V.addClass("logo-align-middle"),Q.addClass("logo-align-middle")),"Right"===u&&(V.removeClass("logo-align-left"),V.removeClass("logo-align-middle"),Q.removeClass("m-inline-s"),Q.removeClass("logo-align-middle"),V.addClass("logo-align-right"),Q.addClass("m-inline-e")),5===f&&(X.show(),Y.hide(),Z.hide(),W.removeClass("two-stamp-row-height"),W.removeClass("three-stamp-row-height"),W.addClass("one-stamp-row-height")),10===f&&(X.show(),Y.show(),Z.hide(),W.removeClass("one-stamp-row-height"),W.removeClass("three-stamp-row-height"),W.addClass("two-stamp-row-height")),15===f&&(X.show(),Y.show(),Z.show(),W.removeClass("one-stamp-row-height"),W.removeClass("two-stamp-row-height"),W.addClass("three-stamp-row-height")),W.css("background-color",m)})});
```

### Video of problem

*Loading time is slow because of screen recording*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VpMl.jpg

Comment: There's a lot of repetition in your code that could be eliminated with a little planning. That looks like a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: @isherwood yeah, the code is still very young and will be refactored! Maybe that wold help with loading times?